# Can't start gulp in terminal

Tags: terminal, server, gulp

I'm trying to start gulp server to enable the Web Starter Kit. So far I've successfully installed all of the needed dependencies (Sass 3.4.13, gulp@3.8.11 and node), but I can't get the gulp server started from my project directory.

Thanks.

Comment: Please give us more information. Which commands do you use, do you have any special error messages? Are all your local dependencies installed?

Comment: After running the command from cd my-project
npm install
npm install gulp -g

Comment: After running the command from:
cd my-project
npm install
npm install gulp -g

It says it's installed Phantomjs binary, etc..but I think specifically for the command:  **npm install gulp -g** - I get an error message, logged as  error Darwin 14.1.0, and Please try running this command again as root/Administrat

Comment: Than you should do that :-) try running it with `sudo npm install -g gulp`

Comment: Best solution I could find currently is this one https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions option2